Sampling theory - Can 2 samples drawn from nested frames, and based on 2 different (correlated) stratification variables, be considered independent?
Suppose that we have two samples (say, a and b) that are drawn from two different frames (say, 1 and 2) of the same population. In particular, suppose the frames are "nested" as shown in the attached sub-figure (a), taken from Lohr (2022). Figure. In other words, Frame 2 represents a sub-population of Frame 1.
Both samples are drawn according to a stratified random sampling scheme, namely, frames 1 and 2 are divided into known strata and units are drawn at random within each stratum. To draw sample a, Frame 1 is stratified according to a characteristic X, whereas to draw b, Frame 2 is stratified according to a different characteristic Y.
Suppose X and Y are correlated at the population level.
Can I say that the two samples a and b are independent? Even tough units in frames 1 and 2 are drawn at random conditional on each stratum, I am puzzled by the fact that at the population level the stratification variables are correlated.
Consequently, I am not sure whether the joint probability of inclusion for a unit i in both samples, $P(i \in a, i \in b)$, can be factorized as follows: $P(i \in a, i \in b) = P(i \in a)P(i \in b)$.
A similar setting (or the same setting, I am not sure) seems to be discussed in Bankier (1986), where samples a and b are said to be independent, but the correlation of the stratification variables at the population level is not discussed.
References
Bankier, M. (1986). Estimators based on several stratified samples with applications to multiple frame surveys. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 81:1074-1079.
Lohr, S. (2022). Multiple-frame surveys for a multiple-data-source world. Survey Methodology, 47:229-263.
